# How to convert the below SQL Data to the below given JSON data

Tags: .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I'm getting the below data from SQL.

```
Person  Occupation  Salary  Count
Ajay    Farmer      5000    1
Ajay    Barber      6000    1
Ajay    Carpenter   8000    1
Mahesh  Farmer      3000    1
Mahesh  Barber      8000    1
Mahesh  Carpenter   9000    1
```

I need to convert it to the following JSON format: I tried but am failing at applying proper groups.

```
{
  "Ajay": [
    {
      "Job Details": [
        {
          "Occupation": "Farmer",
          "Salary": "5000",
          "count": 1
        },
        {
          "Occupation": "Barber",
          "Salary": "6000",
          "count": 1
        },
        {
          "Occupation": "Carpenter",
          "Salary": "8000",
          "count": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "Mahesh": [
    {
      "Job Details": [
        {
          "Occupation": "Farmer",
          "Salary": "3000",
          "count": 1
        },
        {
          "Occupation": "Barber",
          "Salary": "8000",
          "count": 1
        },
        {
          "Occupation": "Carpenter",
          "Salary": "9000",
          "count": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please show us *how* you are converting it to JSON.

Comment: It is almost impossible without dynamic SQL, as SQL Server does not support dynamic JSON keys

Comment: I tried creating two models. One Person Model and Other details Model. But I'm stuck at creating models itself.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated to be more in-line with OP's desired results**

With a little string manipulation

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Person] varchar(50),[Occupation] varchar(50),[Salary] int,[Count] int)  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('Ajay','Farmer',5000,1)
,('Ajay','Barber',6000,1)
,('Ajay','Carpenter',8000,1)
,('Mahesh','Farmer',3000,1)
,('Mahesh','Barber',8000,1)
,('Mahesh','Carpenter',9000,1)


 ;with cte as (
 Select Person,JS= (Select [Occupation]=Occupation
                          ,[Salary]    =Salary
                          ,[Count]     =Count
                      From @YourTable where Person=A.Person
                      FOR JSON PATH,Root('Job Details')
                   )
 From @YourTable A
 Group By Person
)
Select '{'+string_agg('"'+string_escape(Person,'json')+'":['+JS+']',',')+'}'
 From  cte
```

**Results**

```
{
    "Ajay": [{
        "Job Details": [{
            "Occupation": "Farmer",
            "Salary": 5000,
            "Count": 1
        }, {
            "Occupation": "Barber",
            "Salary": 6000,
            "Count": 1
        }, {
            "Occupation": "Carpenter",
            "Salary": 8000,
            "Count": 1
        }]
    }],
    "Mahesh": [{
        "Job Details": [{
            "Occupation": "Farmer",
            "Salary": 3000,
            "Count": 1
        }, {
            "Occupation": "Barber",
            "Salary": 8000,
            "Count": 1
        }, {
            "Occupation": "Carpenter",
            "Salary": 9000,
            "Count": 1
        }]
    }]
}
```

Comment: Hum, my name has `"` in it and my username has a `\\`, now what?

Comment: @Charlieface Clearly if such edge items exist, they would need to be escaped.

Comment: Almost impossible in a single query (no functions) with *correct* escaping. These are not major edge cases, they come up all over the place, and at the very least you should put in a health warning

Comment: … +string_escape(Person,'json')+…

Comment: ..@JohnCappelletti .. sure .. `select * from openjson('{"a\"\\b":"123"}');
select json_value('{"a\"\\b":"123"}', '$."'+string_escape('a"\b', 'json')+'"')`

Comment: @lptr Yup... valid JSON., but that is one UGLY key  :)